# Check camera existence in ios phonegap

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, cordova

I want to check camera existence before showing the two source types when taking a picture in my `phonegap` application.  For example, iPad 1 doesn't have an Camera, therefore I don't want to show the popup to select source type from `Camera` and `My Photos`. Is there something in `phonegap` that tell me camera exists in this device or not?

Comment: have you got answer ????

Comment: i have added device specific check {DEVICE_TYPE!="ipad"}

Comment: I am not getting .. and how I know it is ipad1 or ipad2

Comment: actually i did't get a perfect solution yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there doesn't appear to be a way to query camera existence.

This is not ideal, but it could be a fail safe for you. If the device doesn't have a camera, a call to getPicture will fall into the fail handler, which returns a message. When the camera isn't available, that message is: "no camera available". So you could handle that failure once, then persist something in user settings, which you could query going forward. Like I said, not ideal. If the API can report this specific failure, it should also provide a way to check existence.

fail: function (message) {
    if (message == "no camera available") {
        // save this somewhere so next time we don't have to rely on the fail handler to tell us the camera doesn't exist
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do just this, so I added it to a plug in that I made to do various tasks. Only iOS versions so far.

TomPhonegapUtility.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
@interface TomPhonegapUtility : CDVPlugin
- (void) isCameraAvailable:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end
```

TomPhonegapUtility.m

```
#import "TomPhonegapUtility.h"
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
@implementation TomPhonegapUtility
- (void) isCameraAvailable:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = nil;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsInt:1];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsInt:0];
    }
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
@end
```

TomPhonegapUtility.js

```
function TomPhoneGapUtility () {
    this.isCameraAvailable = function(successCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, function(){}, "TomPhonegapUtility", "isCameraAvailable", []);
    }
}
```

How to use

```
var util = new TomPhoneGapUtility();
util.isCameraAvailable(function(hasCamera) {
    if (hasCamera) alert("YES");
    else alert("NO");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the device model string from UIDevice class and check this

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to call this code to check for existence of a camera on any device.

```
if (typeof navigator.camera !== "undefined") { 
  // We are safe to use the camera 
} else { 
  // Bad news no camera 
}
```

Comment: Just curious if u tried this and whether it worked for you. thanks.

Comment: this does not work, tested on Cordova 3.2 and iPad 1

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this when trying to use the HTML5 way of taking a picture :

```
if (typeof navigator.device !== 'undefined' && typeof navigator.device.capture !== 'undefined' && typeof navigator.device.capture.captureImage !== 'undefined') {
   // Can take a picture
} else {
   // No camera
}
```

Keep in mind that if you have used this solution or the previous one on the IOS simulator, it will give you a reliable answer, the simulator seem to return that it has a camera but is not able to simulate the taking of a picture and will return an error 20 ...

I am not happy with the if statement, if anybody know how to write this in a more logical way, please let me know, my JS knowhow is limited.

Comment: this does not work, tested on Cordova 3.2 and iPad 1

Answer (score 0):

I think this explains it well, if you haven't found the answer as of yet: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera