# Checking for camera access in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Is there a way to check if the device in question supports camera access or not (if indeed it has a camera!).

I need to display different things depending on whether the device can actually take a picture or not, and I'm struggling to find what variable or object to check.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that I'm using PhoneGap Build to build the application, so this needs to be in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using Phonegap in? Android or iOS? If Android you can try this:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager(); 
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) { 
    // Yay, we have a camera. 
}
```

You're basically creating a packet manager to detect if there is a camera for the platform. [Source.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/S7YDBeoWKSk)

If you're talking about iOS there is a question about that already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736973/check-camera-existence-in-ios-phonegap).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Both/All/Everything so the above doesn't help at all I'm afraid. As I mentioned, I am building the application externally and building the native app via PhoneGap Build.